# How to get length in milliseconds of video from URL without video view in Android?

Tags: android

I am making a Media player in Android. I require a code to get length of video without using a video view.

I saw many pages in Stack overflow but ever page used to show how to get length of a video in video view but i require without video view.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You could use the [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) to get such an information. This class is meant to be used by users who wants to get specific informations about a media without having to use the `MediaPlayer`.

Here's a sample of how to use it :

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(your_data_source);
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong( time );
long duration = timeInmillisec / 1000;
long hours = duration / 3600;
long minutes = (duration - hours * 3600) / 60;
long seconds = duration - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60);
```

Comment: This Code Dose Not Work On Android 2.2 And API < 10

Comment: No, the `MediaMetadataRetriever` class only exists on API10+.

Comment: I just ran this code and it's pretty slow when only querying like 20 videos.

Comment: Yes, the `MediaMetadataRetriever` causes the framework to actually parse the media for special headers or metadata frames, so I believe it can take some time, especially if it fetches a remote media.

Comment: @HalimQarroum I get this error 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                                                                         at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriev
I am passing remote url (not a local file path)

Comment: @eawedat This may be related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566480/mediametadataretriever-setdatasource-throws-illegalargumentexception

Comment: @HalimQarroum , after reading there, it seems that we should replace the line 
 retriever.setDataSource(URL); with
 retriever.setDataSource(URL, new HashMap<String, String>()); and it works