# MediaMetadataRetriever setDataSource throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, mediametadataretriever

I'm trying to get the size of a remote video using this class and i'm getting IllegalArgumentException if the video is remote.

the video is an mp4 stored in one server...

the video plays correctly if i play it with mediaplayer, but it gives the error if i try to do this:

```
try {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new  MediaMetadataRetriever();
    Bitmap bmp = null;      
    retriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
    bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime();           
    videoHeight = (int) (bmp.getHeight()*((float)getIntWidth()/bmp.getWidth()));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the error is thrown in this line:

```
retriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
```

and uri contains `Uri.parse("http://www.myweb.com/myvideo.mp4");`

what is wrong in the code?

```
12-19 13:38:08.610: W/System.err(13333): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
12-19 13:38:08.611: W/System.err(13333):    at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:175)
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 28):

Maybe you are running into [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35794) bug. If so try:

```
try {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new  MediaMetadataRetriever();
    Bitmap bmp = null;      
    retriever.setDataSource("http://www.myweb.com/myvideo.mp4", new HashMap<String, String>());
    bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime();           
    videoHeight = (int) (bmp.getHeight()*((float)getIntWidth()/bmp.getWidth()));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If that doesn't work you can always try [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever):

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new  FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();

try {
    Bitmap bmp = null;      
    retriever.setDataSource("http://www.myweb.com/myvideo.mp4"));
    bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime();           
    videoHeight = (int) (bmp.getHeight()*((float)getIntWidth()/bmp.getWidth()));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

retriever.release();
```

Comment: The method setDataSource(String) in the type MediaMetadataRetriever is not applicable for the arguments (String, HashMap<String,String>)

Comment: Method signature here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29

Comment: FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever only needs 5 MB of space. You should be making individual APK's for each architecture when using the NDK.

Comment: I thought you can add the maven repo and use ffmpegmediametadataretriever, or did i missunderstood the concept? +1 For the possible answer

Comment: That's is now the preferred method since Android Studio has replaced Eclipse.

Comment: I went thru the bug pointed by @WilliamSeemann and found : 

`Discovered that exist a new method: setDataSource(link, headers);
I solved this problem with this:

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
 mmr.setDataSource(link, new HashMap<String, String>());
else
 mmr.setDataSource(link);`

It worked for me

Answer (score 10):

I was getting the same error, I am using android 10.

I solved just putting `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in Manifest inside `application`.

See here

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I have already set the "android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" but still facing the same error

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was creating a simple metadata extraction test app, so I copied a file to my phone using adb, like so:

```
adb push 350950598.mp4 /sdcard/Movies
```

**but** I forgot to add the read external storage directory permission in the app manifest.

Specifically:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="my.cool.package.name">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Adding those permissions fixed it for me, even for the simple file string call:

```
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(movie.getPath());
```

And of course, if you're targeting API 23+ marshmallow then you'll have to dynamically ask for those permissions, as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new  MediaMetadataRetriever();
    Bitmap bmp = null;      
    retriever.setDataSource(uri.toString(), new HashMap<String, String>());
    bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime();           
    videoHeight = (int) (bmp.getHeight()*((float)getIntWidth()/bmp.getWidth()));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are uses android 10 or above one then you need to mention **requestLegacyExternalStorage** to true.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Note : if by doing this still you're facing the same issue then you need to reinstall the app. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to give runtime permissions if you are using Android Marshmallow or later.

Android Manifest File:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="my.cool.package.name">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
```

Then add code for runtime permissions in your activity. After that, run your application and it should work.

Comment: Why does it need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?