# Android 10 : API 29 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I want to get the cover photo from audio file
the application work for android 10+ and android 9 but in android 10 it give me an error

```
//this is my code

 private byte[] getAlbumArt(String uri) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(uri);
        byte[] art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        retriever.release();
        return art;
    }
```

error :

```
Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-09-18 22:19:53.826 23193-23193/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.MusicPlayer.musicplayervip, PID: 23193
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:77)
```

help, please

Comment: Hi, not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566480/mediametadataretriever-setdatasource-throws-illegalargumentexception/27597053

Comment: Hi; thx for comment  : but now i have another traceback :

```java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever._setDataSource(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:103)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code didn't give a traceback and keep the app working but doesn't work perfectly
it just ignores the image

```
private byte[] getAlbumArt(String uri) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14){
            try {
                retriever.setDataSource(uri, new HashMap<String, String>());
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            // something went wrong with the file, ignore it and continue
        }
        }
        else {
            retriever.setDataSource(uri);
        }
        byte[] art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        retriever.release();
        return art;
    }
```