# How to get duration of remote video in android?

Tags: android

I am making a media player where I am showing videos from the remote server(e.g. youtube). I have shown a list of videos but I am unable to get the length of videos.
(I have searched on this site but I got answers regarding how to get time duration of the video which is locally stored.
I am giving the link to one of such question.
[How to get length in milliseconds of video from URL without video view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259552/how-to-get-length-in-milliseconds-of-video-from-url-without-video-view-in-androi/46270619?noredirect=1#comment79503752_46270619))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer mp= new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(context,uri);
int durartion = mp.getDuration();
```